# CSS Table growing outside div height

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Good morning everybody!

I'm trying to make a table with size based on %. The width works fine, but i'm having some problems with height. When te user resizes the screen to a certain size the table just stop decreasing it's height, growing outside the div. Below some prints:

Normal size

[image: normal screen]

Resized screen

[image: resized screen]

I've already tried to change the display, the overflow, the position, all without success. When it comes to a certain size the table just stop decreasing it's height.

Below the css to the table and the parenting div:

```
.tblMotivos {
    table-layout:fixed;
    border: 0 solid white;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%!important;
    min-height: 100%!important;
}

.divFundoMotivos{
    padding: 0 !important;
    background-color: white;
    height:88%!important;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
        <div class="col-sm-12 divFundoMotivos">
            <table class="tblMotivos" border="1" id="tblMotivos" style="table-layout:fixed;">
                <thead style="background-color:darkgray;">
                    <tr style="border-color:white;">
                        <td class="tdHeaderMotivos" style="width:44%;padding-left:1%;">Motivo</td>
                        <td class="tdHeaderMotivos" style="width:16%;">#</td>
                        <td class="tdHeaderMotivos" style="width:20%;">Meta</td>
                        <td class="tdHeaderMotivos" style="width:20%;">Perf.</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if motivos.Count > 0 Then
                        @for each motivo As motivoRetencao In motivos
                            @<tr>
                                <td class="tdBodyMotivos" style="padding-left:2%;">@motivo.motivo</td>
                                <td class="tdBodyMotivos tdBodyMotivosValor">@motivo.qtde</td>
                                <td class="tdBodyMotivos tdBodyMotivosValor">@motivo.meta %</td>
                                <td class="tdBodyMotivos tdBodyMotivosValor fontWhite" style="@(If(motivo.performance >= motivo.meta, "background-color:green", If(motivo.performance >= ((motivo.meta * 85) / 100), "background-color:yellow;color:black!important", "background-color:red")))">@motivo.performance %</td>
                            </tr>
                        Next
                    End If
                </tbody>
             </table>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Comment: can you provide html that can be viewed in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i agree with using media query
here is the default media query used by twitter bootstrap
https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

implementing that media, you will need to adjust some properties such as font size, etc based on screen size to fit your need

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I resized the font according to the screen size and it solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with css `display: table;` mixed with the `height` property also in the past. Most browser consider the `height` on browser property to be actually `min-height`. If the table require more height, it will simply take it... And `min + max-height` are not considered by Firefox (but they are by Chrome).

Your best bet would be either doing responsive content INSIDE the table, using `inline-block` or `flexbox` instead of table or try to use some javascript for responsiveness...

Hope it help.

**Guides that might help you:**

Guide for flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Guide for centering in css: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

**References:**

[min-height and table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858040/min-height-and-table-cells)

from: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-height

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

from: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells. A 'height' value of 'auto' for a 'table-row' means the row height used for layout is MIN. MIN depends on cell box heights and cell box alignment (much like the calculation of a line box height). CSS 2.1 does not define how the height of table cells and table rows is calculated when their height is specified using percentage values. CSS 2.1 does not define the meaning of 'height' on row groups.
>
> In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the content. The table cell's 'height' property can influence the height of the row (see above), but it does not increase the height of the cell box.

Comment: thanks for the help! I'll take a deep look into flexbox, seems to be a good alternative. But for now just resizing the font dynamically according to the screen size solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the text responsive, this would give you some more space.

or you could use a media query to remove the margins between the cells at certain heights.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I resized the font according to the screen size and it solved! Thanks.